# In the parallel running process of a c++ program, how to count the memory read and write times of each thread in real time?

Tags: c++, linux, parallel-processing

I want to implement a deterministic parallel multithreaded code that uses memory access times as a deterministic clock.

How to implement it?

It would be nice to have a code example, or tell me which reference manuals might have interfaces to implement this feature

Comment: _"...deterministic parallel multithreaded..."_ you will need a real-time OS not generic Linux.  The OS scheduler will break the  deterministic  part of your requirements.

Comment: Actually, this is even worst, the processor itself is not much deterministic. To be more precise, the instruction execution is typically chaotic. Out of order, branch prediction, speculative execution, instruction level-parallelism, address randomization, caching combined with OS scheduling makes the exact execution simply impossible to predict. Not to mention hardware bugs like JCC impacting the execution regarding the address of the JCC... On top of that, there are hardware counters but AFAIK they are not 100% precise and no possible hook at this level.

Comment: I think the best you can do is playing with page faults like valgrind does or implement this in a compiler if you can rebuild the application. However, this dramatically slows down execution (especially in the first case). In the second case, it can break optimization and change the access pattern, not to mention the hook will need to access memory too...

Comment: For the same program and the same input, the computer executes twice, the cpu's number of instructions (or memory read and write times) may also be different?

Comment: Yes, they may be different, due to preemptive multithreading and CPU contention with other running processes.

Comment: The `RDTSC` instruction might be of interest to you (although I don't think it quite does what you want):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.